# How to access a Node service from a container running in a Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

At time of the writing, it is possible for a docker container to access to a service running on the host machine by using the `--add-host` switch.

```
docker run --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.534 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.176 ms
```

Inside the container, the name `host.docker.internal` will resolve to the host running the `dockerd` daemon. If I have a `openldap` process running on the host,  `docker run --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` allows me to access the ldap server via the URL `ldap://host.docker.internal:389` inside the container.

Assuming `docker` is the container runtime used by a k8s cluster, is there a way for a container to access a `service/process/tcp port` running on the Node.
[image]

Comment: You can use the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to inject the node's name or IP address (`status.hostIP`).  This is most useful for DaemonSet-managed pods, though; you might be better off trying to run everything in Kubernetes than mixing different container-management systems.

Comment: I am very new to k8s. What about [HostAliases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) ? somehow discover the node IP address in the deployment file, maybe via the `status.hostIP`

Comment: The easiest way to set this up will be to run the LDAP server in Kubernetes too, and then you can use ordinary [Kubernetes DNS names](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) to call from one to the other.  I think it's a little unusual for a Kubernetes worker node to also be running other unmanaged Docker containers.